# Choose to plot the line over the "edge" of the graph instead (and loop around), instead of across the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, cheminformatics

So, I have a plot of the dihedral angle of a bond. The y-axis is only from 0-360, the x-axis is the frame (think timestep). I need the plot to "loop" back around to zero if the value goes above 360, and to plot the shortest distance between two points (if need be going over the edge of the graph and "looping" back around instead of across the graph).
[image: two plots: d5 and d3]

The plot of d3 looks okay, but in reality needs to jump over the edge of the graph instead of across it.

the plot of d5 has a significant problem, for a small rotation there is a massive jump only because it happens to go just below zero degrees.

I would like for both these plots to plot towards the bottom (towards zero) and reappear at the top of the plot, effectively choosing the shortest distance between data points. I do not want solutions involving translation of the plots to remove these artefacts (it works, I've done it, but you loose information on the true value of the angle). Solutions that can plot "below zero" (so a y-axis from 300 to 360|0 to 200 to 300) are also great. Solutions using other libraries are perfectly fine. If needed I can provide the dataset.

Example of what I'd like it to do (green line)
[image: Example of what I'd like it to do (green line)]

I have tried to find similar solutions to no avail. The questions regarding periodic boundaries use numpy dataset mask to hide certain jumps, but they have continuous functions (where as mine are "jumpy").

Thank you for any help, I'd really appreciate it.

Datasets(made them a little smaller than on the graph, keeping only the skips):

D3:

```
x = [41.0, 43.0, 45.0, 47.0, 49.0, 51.0, 53.0, 55.0, 57.0, 59.0, 61.0, 63.0, 65.0, 67.0, 69.0, 71.0, 73.0, 75.0, 77.0, 79.0, 81.0, 83.0, 85.0, 87.0, 89.0, 91.0, 93.0, 95.0, 97.0, 99.0, 101.0, 103.0, 105.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 117.0, 119.0, 121.0, 123.0, 125.0, 127.0, 129.0, 131.0, 133.0, 135.0, 137.0, 139.0, 141.0, 143.0, 145.0, 147.0, 149.0, 151.0, 153.0, 155.0, 157.0, 159.0]

y = [45.6501, 37.4855, 40.4035, 51.4948, 55.8648, 48.9723, 60.4494, 42.7136, 20.6929, 36.7847, 44.4601, 54.04, 52.4895, 45.1991, 46.8203, 44.5827, 65.8803, 53.5398, 69.5158, 46.5372, 37.1557, 43.9031, 39.9325, 35.5248, 34.3531, 57.8377, 37.9208, 26.6508, 27.2333, 49.3798, 47.8627, 54.2795, 50.0892, 40.9849, 37.4014, 300.7947, 299.4254, 288.5113, 313.2906, 319.0095, 291.0726, 308.075, 298.451, 311.1485, 320.4832, 303.9229, 310.4584, 325.6287, 307.7328, 301.5581, 308.7813, 308.6791, 305.1343, 307.5148, 334.6374, 310.476, 315.6943, 326.0586, 298.6766, 305.6225]
```

Minimum working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, linewidth = 1.2, label = 'd3')
ax.set_yticks([t for t in range(0,390,30)])
ax.set_xticks([t for t in range(50,200,50)])
ax.legend(loc='lower right',prop={'size': 14})
plt.show()
```

Comment: 1. You could draw the plot on polar coordinates. I would expect that to work. Most likely, however, you are going to have to process your data to fit within a specific angular range. It is not hard to do: just iterate over the rows of data, converting negative angles by adding 360 to them.

Comment: Hi thank you! The data is in the angular range 0-360 (all positive), I tried to use pyplot.polar() directly. The result is pretty but a mess. I'd like to keep it on a non circular plot too, it's more legible

Comment: Try posting the data set (if possible) to github or some other public area. I'll take a look

Comment: I put a reduced version of the dataset in the post, thanks again

Comment: Perfect - I'll take a look later today

Comment: But - your data do not contain the jumps. How do you know they are there? You can always simulate your desired graph but shouldn't it first and foremost reflect your data?

Comment: Thanks for the re-formatting! The data is a selection of timeframes from a MD (Molecular Dynamics) simulation, if I were to use all the data points it would show smooth rotation around the bond. There are millions data points though, I initially save 1 every 250 000 then reduce it to 1000, then plot 500. The longer jump across the graph is not the physically correct one, the bond rotates the shorter way around (60°-0°-300°) not the longer way (60°-300°).

Comment: I see, makes sense now. Do you know where to insert this jump in your graph in terms of x-value or x-index? Or do you want the script to determine this? Might be difficult for d5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic Python, as indicated by your lists, and not higher libraries like `numpy`, you can separate the two parts of the plot with basic functions. However, coming to think about your specific problem, you might prefer a polar plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#two subplots with two different approaches
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(5, 10))

#first approach - separating the list at the jump point
ymin = 0
ymax = 360

#pseudo-threshold calculation, just the first index in your list with a value above the threshold
threshold = 100
breakpoint = next(a[0] for a in enumerate(y) if a[1] > threshold)

#separating the lists at this breakpoint, creating intermediate point
y1 = y[:breakpoint] + [ymin]
y2 = [ymax] + y[breakpoint:]
x12 = 0.5 * (x[breakpoint-1] + x[breakpoint])
x1 = x[:breakpoint] + [x12]
x2 = [x12] + x[breakpoint:]

#plotting of the upper subplot
ax1.plot(x1, y1, c="r", label="jump")
ax1.plot(x2, y2, c="r")
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)


#second approach - a polar plot    
#convert deg into rad, here with numpy
import numpy as np
angle = np.deg2rad(y)

#plot the second subplot using polar coordinates
ax2 = plt.subplot(212, projection='polar')
ax2.plot(angle, x, c="r", label = "same jump")

#making it look nicer with clockwise rotation and 0 degree at the top
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax2.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax2.set_rlabel_position(180)
ax2.set_ylim(0.9 * x[0], 1.1 * x[-1])
ax2.legend(loc=(-0.07,0.97))


plt.show()
```

which gives you both views for comparison:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect and super simple! I was trying something unnecessarily complicated. The polar plot is cool! I'd not realized you needed to use radians XD Anyway I learnt a lot!

Comment: I'm also going to make a couple modifications to use a threshold involving derivatives and to catch multiple "skips". This was the lightbulb I needed to light up first though!

Comment: I have an idea how to deal better with cases like d5 but it needs some refinement. At the moment, it is working but not beautiful. But: If you come up with a better solution, you can always post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about the other problem - how to detect the transitions. Usually, peak detection of signals is difficult but in your case, the condition is rather simple: If the change between two data points is more than 180°, then you should plot it over the border. Here now my suggestion using `numpy` in a rather awkward way with a loop. [I have been asking for suggestions of how to improve the segment extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64784980/8881141), alas, no enlightening answers came. At least the code works.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

ymin = 0
ymax = 360
colour = "blue"

xarr, yarr = np.asarray([x, y])

#create index array for all points with jumps by more than 180 degrees
ind = list(np.where(np.abs(np.diff(yarr, append=yarr[-1])) > np.mean([ymin, ymax])))[0]

#if ind is not empty extract segment
if ind.size:
    #found breakpoints 
    for i, j in enumerate(ind):
        #first segment
        if i==0:
            #first trace
            xcurr = np.copy(xarr[:j+2])
            ycurr = np.copy(yarr[:j+2])
            xcurr[-1] = np.mean(xcurr[-2:]) 
            ycurr[-1] = (ymin, ymax)[ycurr[-1]<np.mean([ymin, ymax])]
        #all following segments  
        else:
            xcurr = np.copy(xarr[ind[i-1]:j+2])
            ycurr = np.copy(yarr[ind[i-1]:j+2])
            xcurr[0] = np.mean(xcurr[:2]) 
            ycurr[0] = (ymin, ymax)[ycurr[0]<np.mean([ymin, ymax])]
            xcurr[-1] = np.mean(xcurr[-2:]) 
            ycurr[-1] = (ymin, ymax)[ycurr[-1]<np.mean([ymin, ymax])]
        
        plt.plot(xcurr, ycurr, c=colour)
            
    #last segment
    xcurr = np.copy(xarr[j:])
    ycurr = np.copy(yarr[j:])
    xcurr[0] = np.mean(xcurr[:2]) 
    ycurr[0] = (ymin, ymax)[ycurr[0]<np.mean([ymin, ymax])]
   
else:
    #ind was empty - plot entire array
    xcurr = np.copy(xarr)
    ycurr = np.copy(yarr)

plt.plot(xcurr, ycurr, c=colour)

plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 13))
plt.show()
```

Sample output with the test data below for multiple jumps

[image]

Test data:

```
x = [41.0, 43.0, 45.0, 47.0, 49.0, 51.0, 53.0, 55.0, 57.0, 59.0, 61.0, 63.0, 65.0, 67.0, 69.0, 71.0, 73.0, 75.0, 77.0, 79.0, 81.0, 83.0, 85.0, 87.0, 89.0, 91.0, 93.0, 95.0, 97.0, 99.0, 101.0, 103.0, 105.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 117.0, 119.0, 121.0, 123.0, 125.0, 127.0, 129.0, 131.0, 133.0, 135.0, 137.0, 139.0, 141.0, 143.0, 145.0, 147.0, 149.0, 151.0, 153.0, 155.0, 157.0, 159.0]
y = [45.6501, 37.4855, 40.4035, 31.4948, 155.8648, 148.9723, 180.4494, 142.7136, 220.6929, 236.7847, 244.4601, 254.04, 252.4895, 245.1991, 246.8203, 244.5827, 265.8803, 253.5398, 269.5158, 246.5372, 237.1557, 243.9031, 239.9325, 235.5248, 234.3531, 257.8377, 37.9208, 26.6508, 27.2333, 349.3798, 347.8627, 354.2795, 350.0892, 340.9849, 337.4014, 300.7947, 99.4254, 88.5113, 13.2906, 19.0095, 191.0726, 208.075, 198.451, 111.1485, 120.4832, 103.9229, 110.4584, 125.6287, 107.7328, 101.5581, 108.7813, 108.6791, 105.1343, 107.5148, 134.6374, 110.476, 15.6943, 26.0586, 98.6766, 105.6225]
```