# How can I plot time-series on matplotlib polar plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

Unsure if a `polar` plot is exactly what I should be using to accomplish this. But, essentially, I have multiple time-series (just amplitude vs. time), each corresponding to a different angle in degrees. For example, I have ampl. vs time at 5 degrees, 10 degrees, 15, etc. For angles `0` to `360` at increments of 5, I would like to plot each time series on a circular, or polar plot.

I am attempting to do this with `matplotlib` and the `projection='polar'` flag on. There are 8000 amplitude values for each time-series. They are in a `numpy array` called `data`. To test plotting the time-series associated with 5-degrees, I made a `numpy array` of 8000 5's with `5*np.ones(8000)` so that they are the same length.

```
thetas=np.arange(0,365,5) #make 0 to 360 degrees at increments of 5

ax=plt.subplot(111,projection='polar') #turn on polar projection
ax.plot(5*np.ones(8000),data) 

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image: polar_example]

You can see these data are not plotting along the 5-degree line, nor does it look like any amplitudes are showing (there should be squiggles up and down varying with time). Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Example of what I want (each color line is a different time-series)
[image]

Comment: You have seemingly three variables (angle, time, amplitude), but you only plot two (angle, distance). I cannot follow what are you trying to achieve here. As for the angle - you have to convert it, for instance, by using [`np.deg2rad()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.deg2rad.html)

Comment: @Mr.T Essentially, I want to plot a time series, amplitude and time, fixed at different degree intervals. But, I don't need to show axis labels of time and amplitude, I just want to show the squiggles at X degrees. Maybe the polar method isn't the right one for this. The distance from the center would be the time axis if you think about it that way.

Comment: Time-amplitude diagrams can be [easily implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757304/8881141) as a polar plot. What I have problems with is `fixed at different degree intervals` - let's say you have 4 categories, then you would like to plot the first plot between 0 and 90° with 45° being zero, then the next one from 90 to 180° with 135° as zero, etc.? Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: You have only two available dimensions here, when you seem to need 3. Lets say you want to plot all the points of the time series at 5 degrees -- then you only have the radius to represent either amplitude, or time.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you so much for the help, I'm explaining really poorly. Imagine I collect time-amplitude data from X seconds with a sensor set to 0 degrees, then more data after I rotate sensor to 5 degrees, 10 degrees, etc. I want to plot each time series, but rotated so that the axis of the time-series is the degrees that its corresponding data was collected at. Time could run from center of circle to outside edge.

Comment: That would be indeed three parameters in a 2D plot. You could create a [2D polar scatter plot with color as the third variable](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html) - not sure this is what you are aiming at.

Comment: @Mr.T  I added a picture of what I am looking for if that helps at all

Comment: This is what I suggested in the second comment - it has two inherent problems: 1) It is not immediately clear what the angle is for a given curve. You could define the mean value of the amplitudes as the angle (e.g., 15°). But then the curves 10-15-20 and 1000-1500-2000 would look similar. 2) Even worse: The same amplitude value would become larger in its representation toward the periphery.

Comment: @Mr.T You're right, I see what you are saying now. Maybe I just need to plot on many axes and rotate each axis by the certain degree.

Comment: Personally, I would find a normal line plot easier to read. Amplitudes at different angles are extremely difficult to compare. Or maybe you prefer a [3D representation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/polys3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-polys3d-py) with x representing time, y angle, and z amplitude?